# Function to create the Padovan sequence in mips

Tags: assembly, mips

So i am trying to make this sequence which is similiar to Fibonacci, i have done the following code but when i execute, it just displays the comma and a zero, i am rather new to mips so i haven't been able to identify the problem. thank you

```
.data
          prompt1: .asciiz "Enter an integer value\n"
          prompt2: .asciiz "The Padovan sequence numbers are:\n"
          prompt3: .asciiz "You have entered a value between 0 and 2, the sequence value is 1"
          prompt4: .asciiz "You have entered a negative value, the program will exit "
          comma:   .asciiz ","  #Comma to insert between numbers

.text
main:

          #Ask the user for an input
          la   $a0, prompt1
          li   $v0, 4
          #Get the number from the user and move it into another register
          #and branch if the input is less than zero
          li   $v0, 5
          syscall
          move $a0, $v0
          bltz $a0, main_exit
          #Jump and link to the tag and save the result
          move $t2, $v0
          jal padovan
          #Print the message prompt2
          la   $a0, prompt2
          li   $v0, 4
          syscall
          #Print the result
          li   $v0, 1
          move $a0, $t2
          syscall
          #Print the Comma
          la   $a0, comma
          li   $v0, 4
          syscall
          j main

less_than2input:

          la   $a0, prompt3
          li   $v0, 4
          syscall
          #Exit the program
          li   $v0, 10
          syscall

main_exit:
          la   $a0, prompt4
          li   $v0, 4
          syscall
          #Exit the program
          li   $v0, 10
          syscall

padovan:
          bgt  $a0, 2, pado_full   #If the input is greater than 2 jump to the full function
          move $v0, $a0
          jr   $ra

pado_full:
          sub  $sp, $sp, 16
          sw   $ra, 4($sp)
          sw   $a0, 8($sp)

          addi $a0, $a0, -2
          jal  padovan
          sw   $v0, 0($sp)

          addi $a0, $a0, -1
          jal padovan

          lw   $t0, 0($sp)
          add  $v0, $t0, $v0

          lw   $ra, 4($sp)
          lw   $a0, 8($sp)
          addi $sp, $sp, 16

          jr   $ra
```

Answer (score 2):

You're calling a function, which is returning a return value in `$v0`, then almost immediately after calling the function, you clobber `$v0` with the value 4 (syscall code for print string) — this act wipes out the only copy you have of the value of function call.  There are other problems.

---

You need to learn basic debugging skills.

Single step using a small test case through the whole program is the best initial approach — after a while (say when you have the first part of the program working) you might set and run to a breakpoint and single step from there; with the breakpoint approach we can work larger test cases where single stepping the whole program isn't practical.  But to reiterate, you should acquire the skill and habit to single step at least once, every line of code you write.

---

When single stepping, check the following after each instruction executes:

- computation, make sure the computed value makes sense, that the updated value is what you're expecting

  - for arithmetic and load instructions, check the register,
  - for load & store instructions, make sure the memory address being used makes sense
  - for store instructions, check that the memory is updated as expected, and, the surrounding memory was not negatively impacted, as might happen with a `sw` when a `sb` was proper (not your case here though).
- control flow: make sure that the next instruction is the right one to do next

  - for conditional branch instructions, make sure taken vs. not taken matches  expectation for the condition
- AND last, but very important especially here, verify that other important values have not been clobbered by the last instruction "accidentally" wiping something out.

If you follow this approach, you'll see problems after calling `padovan`.